# Is there any way to use more than 1 bootstrap class in Zend Framework?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework

It should sound workaround or something like, but I'll tell you what:

I chose to have a separated "project" with every library I could use. It's like a global library which I included Zend library, Doctrine ORM, JQuery, Blueprint CSS, etc. Then I set the include path. Nothing wrong.

The problem is: I'd like to have also a global bootstrap class inside the library folder and an individual bootstrap class on each project I create for individual use.

I don't know how to set more than 1 bootstrap class. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way i can think of is of make youre own base bootstrap class and extend that instead of the default Zend one. so instead of

```
//application/Bootstrap.php
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
   // project specific
}
```

you would have:

```
// application/Bootstrap.php
<?php
class Bootstrap extends YourNamespace_Bootstrap
{
   // project specific
}

// library/YourNamespace/Bootstrap.php
<?php
class YourNamespace_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
   // library specific
}
```